# How can I disable MongoDB log messages in console?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have this little test script:

```
require 'mongo'

mongo_client = Mongo::Client.new(['127.0.0.1:27017'], :database => 'test')
mongo_client[:collection].insert_one({a: 1})
```

An this is the console output:

```
$ ruby test.rb
D, [2015-05-17T21:12:05.504986 #25257] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | Adding 127.0.0.1:27017 to the cluster. | runtime: 0.0212ms
D, [2015-05-17T21:12:05.531238 #25257] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | COMMAND | namespace=admin.$cmd selector={:ismaster=>1} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 project=nil | runtime: 24.5481ms
D, [2015-05-17T21:12:05.554532 #25257] DEBUG -- : MONGODB | COMMAND | namespace=test.$cmd selector={:insert=>"collection", :documents=>[{:a=>1, :_id=><BSON::ObjectId:0x21935660 data=5558e80553657262a9000000>}], :writeConcern=>{:w=>1}, :ordered=>true} flags=[] limit=-1 skip=0 project=nil | runtime: 21.1718ms
```

I want to disable those log messages, I don't want a dirty STDOUT. I didn't found any option for this in the ruby driver, and also I've tried to edit `/etc/mongod.conf` with these directives (but it didn't fix it):

```
verbose = false
diaglog = 0
```

Any idea? I don't know what else I can try!

Comment: For future visitors, if you want beautiful colored logging similar to active record, you might want to look at [the mongo beautiful logger gem](https://github.com/redline-gh/mongo_beautiful_logger/)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

This logging is coming from the Ruby Mongo driver. The default logging level seems to be `Logger::DEBUG`. Change it to something higher to disable the debug output:

```
Mongo::Logger.logger.level = Logger::FATAL
```

To make the driver log to a logfile instead:

```
Mongo::Logger.logger       = Logger.new('mongo.log')
Mongo::Logger.logger.level = Logger::INFO
```

Note that if you're using the **Mongoid ODM**, then you may want to adjust logging there too:

```
Mongoid.logger       = Logger.new('mongoid.log')
Mongoid.logger.level = Logger::INFO
```

For **[Rails + Mongoid](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-rails/)** in `application.rb`:

```
config.mongoid.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root + '/log/mongoid.log', :warn)

# ...or change the logging level without a new file destination
config.mongoid.logger.level = Logger::INFO
```

Comment: This didn't disable queries from being logged in my console. Adding Mongoid.logger.level = Logger::INFO did the trick.

Comment: That didn't work for me on Mongoid 6. This is what worked when I put it in application.rb 

Mongoid::Config.logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/mongo.log")

Comment: For anyone coming here looking for an answer for Rails and Mongoid in general, this may be set in `mongoid.yml` as well: https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-installation/

Comment: The .logger = ... didn't work in Rails 5.1 (mongo 2.5, mongoid 6.2) but `config.mongoid.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root + '/tmp/mongo.log', :warn)` in an development.rb from https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/master/tutorials/mongoid-rails/ finally cleaned up my console!

Comment: Note - To just set the log level in Rails (without changing the destination): `config.mongoid.logger.level = Logger::INFO`

Comment: Rails.root + '/something/something' -> /something/something in rails 6. Remove leading / from the string solved my issue.

Comment: FYI `Mongo::Logger.logger.level = Logger::FATAL` also works for newer versions of MongoMapper

Answer (score 3):

To disable the debug output for Ruby Mongo Driver(mongoid)
we can add it specific environment file as

> `config.mongoid.logger.level = Logger::INFO`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers didn't work for me.

This works for newer Ruby / Rails Versions:

```rb
config.mongoid.logger = Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log/mongoid.log'), level: :warn)
```